# How to use custom sections in app.config from a t4 template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, t4

I am trying to access a custom section in app.config file from a t4 template in VS2010, but the assembly that defines the custom section cannot be loaded.

I'm using the ConfigurationAccessor to get the section (ref http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/01/23/accessing-app.configweb.config-from-t4-template.aspx).

app.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MyProviders" type="System.Web.Security.MySection, MyAssembly" />
</configSections>

<MyProviders default="SQLMyProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SQLMyProvider" ... connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</MyProviders>
```

Calling this line in the .tt file:

```
MySection section = (MySection)config.Configuration.GetSection("MyProviders");
```

Gives this error:

> Running transformation:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for
>   MyProviders: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'MyAssembly' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

The .tt file references the assembly and so does the project, but this doesn't seem to help loading the config section.
I have tried implementing the MySection class as a tt code block, but can't use that class in app.config either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where you try to retrieve your custom section? I've same trouble using different appdomains. My issue was that my section dll had to be placed in the base directory so appdomain could probe correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think `<configSections>` need full assembly names (version, culture, publickeytoken)

```
type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `MyAssembly` in the `GAC` or just in Visual Studios `PublicAssemblies` folder for it to be able to find it. The location for the latter is `<install_dir>\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`.